# Make a root-level directory in an SVN repository a subdirectory in a different repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have two SVN repositories, structured as follows:

```
-Repo1
--mydir
----...\\subdirectories and files.

-Repo2
--mydir
----mydir
------mydirgrandchild
--------...\\subdirectories and files.
```

The similarity in the names "mydir" is not incidental; all directories named here "mydir"
are actually named the same.

My task is to take `mydir` from under `Repo1`, and place it as is (while maintaining history,
revision numbers etc.) as a child of `mydirgrandchild` in `Repo2`. Note that once copied
it will have (grand and great grand) parents named the same.

I don't know how to approach this. All the solutions I could find online talk about creating a dump of `Repo1` and loading it as is into `Repo2`, but this is not what I need. In my case the root-level folder in `Repo1` will simply become one of the subfolders in `Repo2`.

Help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*svnadmin dump* and *svnadmin load* are the right tools. If the paths in *repo1/* (full history) are disjoint from the paths in *repo1/.../mydirgrandchild/* (head revision), then the following steps should do the job:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repo1 > /tmp/repo1.dump
svnadmin load --parent-dir mydir/mydir/mydirgrandchild /path/to/repo2 < /tmp/repo1.dump
```

It the paths are not disjoint, then you should change the paths in the dump before loading it into *repo2*. See the following links for more information:

- [Is it possible to change dir name in repository by svndumpfilter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486447/is-it-possible-to-change-dir-name-in-repository-by-svndumpfilter)
- https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/SVN-DumpReloc/bin/svn-dump-reloc

To minimize the risk of data corruption, you should test the second step before running it on your real SVN repository. That means you should first create an exact copy of *repo2*. You can use file system tools for this task (e.g. `cp -a`). Don't forget to check if there are absolute paths hardcoded in the *hook scripts*.